# To insert dynamically added rows to Database

Tags: asp.net, ajax

In the below code I have html table with textbox and dropdown and I'm adding new row dynamically and I want to store all the values using ajax but when I click submit button the rows get disappear. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Javascript:

```
function MyFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "New.aspx/InsertData",
        data: "{'Quantity':'" + $("#<%=txtQty.ClientID%>").val() + "','ProductID':'" + $("#<%=ddlProduct.ClientID%>").val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: "true",
        cache: "false",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Success");
            // On success                 
        },
        Error: function(x, e) {
            alert("Fail");
            // On Error
        }
    });
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="txt" id="txtQty" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" Style="width: 100%; height:23px"></asp:DropDownList>


        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Save New" type="submit" OnClientClick="MyFunction()" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void InsertData(string Quantity, string ProductID)
{
        MastersClient Uinsert = new MastersClient();


        Dictionary<string, string> UnitVal = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        UnitVal.Add("Quantity", Quantity.ToString());
        UnitVal.Add("Product", ProductID.ToString());

        Uinsert.InsertUnitTypeDetails(UnitVal); 
}
```

Comment: Is the `InsertData` method really empty?  That might explain the problem.  Also, is `Button1` causing a post-back?  You don't want the same button to invoke an AJAX action *and* a post-back.  That too could cause this problem.

Comment: Where are you binding data to table? After Insert bind table.

Comment: @David On Submit button i am calling ajax but it is not calling server method and rows disappear

Comment: @صفي On Webmethod i want to insert

Comment: @Developer: Well what *is* it doing?  When you debug the JavaScript, is the client-side function called?  Is there an error in the JavaScript console?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does it have the values you expect?  What is the server's response?  Is it also invoking a post-back?  Nobody here can debug this for you.

Comment: please show your data binding code.

Comment: @David it is not calling webmethod

Comment: @Developer: Yes, you've said that already.  But for some reason you refuse to provide us with any information about what the code *is* doing.  We can't find that out for ourselves.  It may look like we're talking to you from inside your computer, but I assure you we are not.  We can't look at the problem for you.  You have to provide us with debugging information.

Comment: @صفي see my edited Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this -

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Save New" type="submit" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

And JavaScript like this-

```
 $(function () {
       $("#Button1").click(function (event) {

            // Prevents Form Submission as you want to save data via AJAX
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "New.aspx/InsertData",
                data: "{'Quantity':'" + $("#<%=txtQty.ClientID%>").val() + "','ProductID':'" + $("#<%=ddlProduct.ClientID%>").val() + "'}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               async: "true",
               cache: "false",
               success: function (msg) {
                   alert("Success");
                   // On success                 
               },
               Error: function (x, e) {
                   alert("Fail");
                   // On Error
               }
           });
       });
   })
```

and make sure you pulling Dynamic data by dynamic Control ID on -

```
data: "{'Quantity':'" + $("#<%=txtQty.ClientID%>").val() + "','ProductID':'" + $("#<%=ddlProduct.ClientID%>").val() + "'}",
```

Comment: Yes its fine but it takes only first row but i want to insert dynamically added rows

Answer (score 0):

try java script like this. this will store all rows of data in the table.

```
$("#Button1").click(function (event) {

            // Prevents Form Submission as you want to save data via AJAX
            event.preventDefault();

            // loop each data row and send insert request
            $("#dataTable tbody > tr").each(function () {

                var quantity = $(this).find("input[id='<%=txtQty.ClientID%>']").val();
                var productID = $(this).find("select[id='<%=ddlProduct.ClientID%>']").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "New.aspx/InsertData",
                    data: "{'Quantity':'" + quantity + "','ProductID':'" + productID + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: "true",
                    cache: "false",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert("Success");
                        // On success                 
                    },
                    Error: function (x, e) {
                        alert("Fail");
                        // On Error
                    }
                        });
            });
        });
```

Comment: It is not calling Ajax method the rows now disaappears